# how would you detect if the mouse cursor is inside a JFrame in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How would you write a method to detect if the mouse cursor is inside a JFrame in java? The method should return true if it is inside or else false.

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: which part you don't understand? Getting the JFrame position, dimensions, getting the current mouse position, or comparing it to the JFrame dimentions ?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without getting the coordinates of the mouse and testing to see if they are in the jframe dimensions?
How do you do it with a hover over event or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a mouse listener and react to the mouseEntered-Event:

```
JFrame.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {
        // your code here
    }
} );
```

Comment: Won't work if other components have MouseListeners, because as soon as the mouse goes over other components a mouseExited() event will be generated.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events are not sufficient (this was the case for me as I wanted to avoid extra calls to `mouseExited` when the mouse cursor entered a button's bounds within a panel), I came up with this short check to add to the beginning of my `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` event handlers:

```
public static boolean isMouseWithinComponent(Component c)
{
    Point mousePos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    Rectangle bounds = c.getBounds();
    bounds.setLocation(c.getLocationOnScreen());
    return bounds.contains(mousePos);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the comment in the original posting you can use the MouseInfo class to get the current location of the mouse. Then you compare this location with the bounds on the frame to return the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mouse listener to your JFrame, and look for mouseEntered and mouseExited events.

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // do your action here
    }

    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // do your action here
    }
});
```